# PostgreSQL Full Text search with Datetime string

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I need some help understanding why PG returns false for this search query:

```
select to_tsvector('2021-07-01T00:57:43Z') @@ to_tsquery('2021-07-01T00<->57<->43Z');
```

Separately:

```
select to_tsvector('2021-07-01T00:57:43Z');
-------------------------------------------------
 '-01':3 '-07':2 '2021':1 '43z':6 '57':5 't00':4

select to_tsquery('2021-07-01T00<->57<->43Z');
                      to_tsquery                       
-------------------------------------------------------
 ( '2021' & '-07' & '-01' & 't00' ) <-> '57' <-> '43z'
```

What is the significance of the parenthesis here? All the lexemes inside the parenthesis are present in the tsvector, and positionally the <-> operators are also satisfied. So why isn't this a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that [will be fixed in v14](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=0c4f355c6a5fd437f71349f2f3d5d491382572b7).  But it looks like the fix was considered too invasive to back-patch, so it will not be fixed in the point releases for the older versions.

Comment: I checked it with both V14 and V15, still didn't work! do you have any further infos or advises?

Comment: The query given in the question works for me (returning true) in v14.  Could it be something to do with your default text search configuration?

Comment: Not sure, I didn't mess with FTS configs other than setting en_US.UTF-8 locale